# Canonical duplicate for Mushroom Planet books

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

There are several [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions for Elamor Cameron's  "Mushroom  Planet" series of books. More than one of these has an accepted answer, and none of them are closed as a duplicate.

Should one be picked as the "canonical" story-id question, and the rest be closed as duplicates of that one?

[And now, for something completely different: The mushrooms are among us](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70827/and-now-for-something-completely-different-the-mushrooms-are-among-us) is the oldest one with an accepted answer.

Comment: Care to link in the various candidates?  To save everyone searching independently?

Answer (score 7):

Mushroom Planet has been used as the answer in ten [story-id](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-id) questions, however it is already marked as a duplicates of
[And now, for something completely different: The mushrooms are among us](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70827/and-now-for-something-completely-different-the-mushrooms-are-among-us) in all five of the questions where it has been accepted as the answer.

- [Kids space travel series featuring 'The Great Ta'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185793/kids-space-travel-series-featuring-the-great-ta/185794#185794)
- [Space travel with spores or mushrooms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93072/space-travel-with-spores-or-mushrooms/93076#93076)
- [I am looking for title of Book about a kid or kids who build a rocket or space ship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182715/i-am-looking-for-title-of-book-about-a-kid-or-kids-who-build-a-rocket-or-space-s/182717#182717)
- [Looking for the title of a YA/Youth sci-fi novel about kids traveling to alien planet where the aliens need sulphur to survive?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246386/looking-for-the-title-of-a-ya-youth-sci-fi-novel-about-kids-traveling-to-alien-p/246392#246392)
- [Science Fiction Story About Two Kids That Build A Spaceship Pre-1994](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216081/science-fiction-story-about-two-kids-that-build-a-spaceship-pre-1994) (acceptance via comment)

The remaining [story-id](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-id) questions with Mushroom Planet as an answer don't have an acceptance, and **are hence ineligible to be marked as duplicates**.

- [Book about two kids going to the moon with an old scientist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266224/book-about-two-kids-going-to-the-moon-with-an-old-scientist/266262#266262)
- [Lost title of a book with an old man advertising for a seat available on his rocket ship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191166/lost-title-of-a-book-with-an-old-man-advertising-for-a-seat-available-on-his-roc/191171#191171)
- [Book Series for MG/Children - About Kind/Gentle Alien Professor/Engineer Working in Basement Laboratory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117336/book-series-for-mg-children-about-kind-gentle-alien-professor-engineer-working/117714#117714)
- [Children's novel: three children (plus dog?) travel to the Moon in pretend spaceship turned real](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66578/childrens-novel-three-children-plus-dog-travel-to-the-moon-in-pretend-space/117667#117667)
- [Book Search: Kid travels to another world; adapts by collecting soil?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155589/book-search-kid-travels-to-another-world-adapts-by-collecting-soil/172611#172611)

I have also searched for the [other books in this series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/69821-the-mushroom-planet) by their titles, and none are found as answers on any of our existing questions.

Comment: Well there's [this question I answered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241490/what-is-the-oldest-story-in-which-a-kid-made-a-spaceship-out-of-junk/241499) but it's a history-of.

Comment: @Spencer - That wouldn't be a dupe of a Story-ID question though